# Why is my assembly program slower than a Python version, printing 16M lines of text numbers?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, performance, assembly, x86

I have a program, no matter why it is needed. At the input we have a number, after executing the program we get another number, the result is written as a string in a text file.
And so 16,777,216 times.

This is a script written in python (ver 3.11):

[Link to .py file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19MGia35Xbycf5FHFTKrVuDdz5bG4k4GA/view?usp=share_link)

```
begin = 0x09000000
stack_mb=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
          0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
result=''
f = open('C:/file.txt','a',encoding='ascii')

while begin <=0x0a000000:
    str_in = str(hex(begin))[2:len(hex(begin))]
    str_in = '0x'+'0'*(8-len(str_in))+str_in
    result=str_in+' 0x'

    r8=int(str_in[2:4],16)
    r11=int(str_in[4:6],16)
    r9=int(str_in[6:8],16)
    r7=int(str_in[8:10],16)
    r14=0

    r15=r8
    if r15+r15 >0xff: r14=0x1b 
    else: r14=0
    r15=(r8*2)^r14
    if r15 > 0xff: r15 -= 0x100
    r14=r15
    stack_mb[0x8]=r14
    if r15+r15 >0xff: r14=0x1b 
    else: r14=0
    r15=(r15*2)^r14
    if r15 > 0xff: r15 -= 0x100
    r13=r15
    stack_mb[0x16]=r13
    if r15+r15 >0xff: r14=0x1b 
    else: r14=0
    r15=(r15*2)^r14
    if r15 > 0xff: r15 -= 0x100
    r14=r15
    r15=r11
    stack_mb[0x4]=r15
    r15=r11
    stack_mb[0x14]=r14

    if r15+r15 >0xff: r14=0x1b 
    else: r14=0
    r15=(r15*2)^r14
    if r15 > 0xff: r15 -= 0x100

    r12=r15
    stack_mb[0x12]=r12

    if r15+r15 >0xff: r14=0x1b 
    else: r14=0
    r15=(r15*2)^r14
    if r15 > 0xff: r15 -= 0x100
    stack_mb[0xc]=r15

    if r15+r15 >0xff: r14=0x1b 
    else: r14=0
    r15=(r15*2)^r14
    if r15 > 0xff: r15 -= 0x100

    r4=r15
    r11=r9
    stack_mb[0x6]=r11
    r15=r9

    if r15+r15 >0xff: r14=0x1b 
    else: r14=0
    r15=(r15*2)^r14
    if r15 > 0xff: r15 -= 0x100

    stack_mb[0xd]=r15

    if r15+r15 >0xff: r14=0x1b 
    else: r14=0
    r15=(r15*2)^r14
    if r15 > 0xff: r15 -= 0x100

    r11=r15
    stack_mb[0xa]=r11

    if r15+r15 >0xff: r14=0x1b 
    else: r14=0
    r15=(r15*2)^r14
    if r15 > 0xff: r15 -= 0x100

    r6=r15
    r5=r7
    r15=r7

    if r15+r15 >0xff: r14=0x1b 
    else: r14=0
    r15=(r15*2)^r14
    if r15 > 0xff: r15 -= 0x100

    stack_mb[0xe]=r15

    if r15+r15 >0xff: r14=0x1b 
    else: r14=0
    r15=(r15*2)^r14
    if r15 > 0xff: r15 -= 0x100

    r7=r15

    if r15+r15 >0xff: r14=0x1b 
    else: r14=0
    r15=(r15*2)^r14
    if r15 > 0xff: r15 -= 0x100

    r9=r15
    r13=stack_mb[0x16]
    r11=stack_mb[0x8]
    r14=stack_mb[0x14]
    r12=stack_mb[0x12]
    r11=r11^r13^r14^r12^r4^stack_mb[0xa]^r6^r9^stack_mb[0x4]^stack_mb[0x6]^r5
    if len(str(hex(r11))) == 3: result+='0'
    result += str(hex(r11))[2:4]
    r11=r8
    r15=stack_mb[0xc]
    r8=stack_mb[0xd]
    r12=r12^r14^r4^r6^r9^r15^r8^r7^r5^r11^stack_mb[0x6]
    if len(str(hex(r12))) == 3: result+='0'
    result += str(hex(r12))[2:4]
    r12=stack_mb[0xe]
    r13=r13^r14^r4^r6^r9^r8^r12^r5^r11^stack_mb[0x4]^stack_mb[0xa]
    if len(str(hex(r13))) == 3: result+='0'
    result += str(hex(r13))[2:4]
    r14=r14^r4^r6^r9^r15^r7^r12^r11^stack_mb[0x8]^stack_mb[0x4]^stack_mb[0x6]
    if len(str(hex(r14))) == 3: result+='0'
    result += str(hex(r14))[2:4]
                                              
    print(result)
    begin+=1
    f.write(result+'\n')

f.close()
```

This is program written on assembler (32-bit, Windows, compiled manually on hex-editor):

[Link to .exe file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WjLGG9dqaA04R7z-nuNjf8Kz69PY5gwK/view?usp=share_link)

```
0:  6a 00                   push   0x0
2:  68 00 00 00 80          push   0x80000000
7:  6a 02                   push   0x2
9:  6a 00                   push   0x0
b:  6a 00                   push   0x0
d:  68 00 00 00 40          push   0x40000000
12: 68 00 20 40 00          push   0x402000
17: ff 15 88 30 40 00       call   DWORD PTR ds:0x403088        //CreateFileA
1d: 8b f8                   mov    edi,eax
1f: 31 db                   xor    ebx,ebx                      //begin
21: 8b 15 10 20 40 00       mov    edx,DWORD PTR ds:0x402010
27: 42                      inc    edx
28: 89 15 10 20 40 00       mov    DWORD PTR ds:0x402010,edx
2e: 8a 1d 10 20 40 00       mov    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x402010
34: 00 db                   add    bl,bl
36: 73 03                   jae    0x3b
38: 80 f3 1b                xor    bl,0x1b
3b: 88 1d 20 20 40 00       mov    BYTE PTR ds:0x402020,bl
41: 00 db                   add    bl,bl
43: 73 03                   jae    0x48
45: 80 f3 1b                xor    bl,0x1b
48: 88 1d 2c 20 40 00       mov    BYTE PTR ds:0x40202c,bl
4e: 00 db                   add    bl,bl
50: 73 03                   jae    0x55
52: 80 f3 1b                xor    bl,0x1b
55: 88 1d 2a 20 40 00       mov    BYTE PTR ds:0x40202a,bl
5b: 8a 1d 11 20 40 00       mov    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x402011
61: 00 db                   add    bl,bl
63: 73 03                   jae    0x68
65: 80 f3 1b                xor    bl,0x1b
68: 88 1d 28 20 40 00       mov    BYTE PTR ds:0x402028,bl
6e: 00 db                   add    bl,bl
70: 73 03                   jae    0x75
72: 80 f3 1b                xor    bl,0x1b
75: 88 1d 24 20 40 00       mov    BYTE PTR ds:0x402024,bl
7b: 00 db                   add    bl,bl
7d: 73 03                   jae    0x82
7f: 80 f3 1b                xor    bl,0x1b
82: 88 1d 36 20 40 00       mov    BYTE PTR ds:0x402036,bl
88: 8a 1d 12 20 40 00       mov    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x402012
8e: 00 db                   add    bl,bl
90: 73 03                   jae    0x95
92: 80 f3 1b                xor    bl,0x1b
95: 88 1d 2e 20 40 00       mov    BYTE PTR ds:0x40202e,bl
9b: 00 db                   add    bl,bl
9d: 73 03                   jae    0xa2
9f: 80 f3 1b                xor    bl,0x1b
a2: 88 1d 22 20 40 00       mov    BYTE PTR ds:0x402022,bl
a8: 00 db                   add    bl,bl
aa: 73 03                   jae    0xaf
ac: 80 f3 1b                xor    bl,0x1b
af: 88 1d 30 20 40 00       mov    BYTE PTR ds:0x402030,bl
b5: 8a 1d 13 20 40 00       mov    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x402013
bb: 00 db                   add    bl,bl
bd: 73 03                   jae    0xc2
bf: 80 f3 1b                xor    bl,0x1b
c2: 88 1d 26 20 40 00       mov    BYTE PTR ds:0x402026,bl
c8: 00 db                   add    bl,bl
ca: 73 03                   jae    0xcf
cc: 80 f3 1b                xor    bl,0x1b
cf: 88 1d 32 20 40 00       mov    BYTE PTR ds:0x402032,bl
d5: 00 db                   add    bl,bl
d7: 73 03                   jae    0xdc
d9: 80 f3 1b                xor    bl,0x1b
dc: 88 1d 34 20 40 00       mov    BYTE PTR ds:0x402034,bl
e2: 8a 1d 20 20 40 00       mov    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x402020
e8: 32 1d 2c 20 40 00       xor    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x40202c
ee: 32 1d 2a 20 40 00       xor    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x40202a
f4: 32 1d 28 20 40 00       xor    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x402028
fa: 32 1d 36 20 40 00       xor    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x402036
100:    32 1d 22 20 40 00       xor    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x402022
106:    32 1d 30 20 40 00       xor    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x402030
10c:    32 1d 34 20 40 00       xor    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x402034
112:    32 1d 11 20 40 00       xor    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x402011
118:    32 1d 12 20 40 00       xor    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x402012
11e:    32 1d 13 20 40 00       xor    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x402013
124:    88 1d 16 20 40 00       mov    BYTE PTR ds:0x402016,bl
12a:    8a 1d 28 20 40 00       mov    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x402028
130:    32 1d 2a 20 40 00       xor    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x40202a
136:    32 1d 36 20 40 00       xor    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x402036
13c:    32 1d 30 20 40 00       xor    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x402030
142:    32 1d 34 20 40 00       xor    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x402034
148:    32 1d 24 20 40 00       xor    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x402024
14e:    32 1d 2e 20 40 00       xor    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x40202e
154:    32 1d 32 20 40 00       xor    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x402032
15a:    32 1d 12 20 40 00       xor    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x402012
160:    32 1d 13 20 40 00       xor    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x402013
166:    32 1d 10 20 40 00       xor    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x402010
16c:    88 1d 17 20 40 00       mov    BYTE PTR ds:0x402017,bl
172:    8a 1d 2c 20 40 00       mov    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x40202c
178:    32 1d 2a 20 40 00       xor    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x40202a
17e:    32 1d 36 20 40 00       xor    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x402036
184:    32 1d 22 20 40 00       xor    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x402022
18a:    32 1d 30 20 40 00       xor    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x402030
190:    32 1d 34 20 40 00       xor    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x402034
196:    32 1d 26 20 40 00       xor    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x402026
19c:    32 1d 2e 20 40 00       xor    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x40202e
1a2:    32 1d 11 20 40 00       xor    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x402011
1a8:    32 1d 13 20 40 00       xor    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x402013
1ae:    32 1d 10 20 40 00       xor    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x402010
1b4:    88 1d 18 20 40 00       mov    BYTE PTR ds:0x402018,bl
1ba:    8a 1d 20 20 40 00       mov    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x402020
1c0:    32 1d 2a 20 40 00       xor    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x40202a
1c6:    32 1d 30 20 40 00       xor    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x402030
1cc:    32 1d 36 20 40 00       xor    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x402036
1d2:    32 1d 34 20 40 00       xor    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x402034
1d8:    32 1d 24 20 40 00       xor    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x402024
1de:    32 1d 32 20 40 00       xor    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x402032
1e4:    32 1d 26 20 40 00       xor    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x402026
1ea:    32 1d 11 20 40 00       xor    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x402011
1f0:    32 1d 12 20 40 00       xor    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x402012
1f6:    32 1d 10 20 40 00       xor    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x402010
1fc:    88 1d 19 20 40 00       mov    BYTE PTR ds:0x402019,bl
202:    31 db                   xor    ebx,ebx
204:    8a 1d 10 20 40 00       mov    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x402010
20a:    01 db                   add    ebx,ebx
20c:    81 c3 50 20 40 00       add    ebx,0x402050
212:    8b 1b                   mov    ebx,DWORD PTR [ebx]
214:    66 89 1d 38 20 40 00    mov    WORD PTR ds:0x402038,bx
21b:    31 db                   xor    ebx,ebx
21d:    8a 1d 11 20 40 00       mov    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x402011
223:    01 db                   add    ebx,ebx
225:    81 c3 50 20 40 00       add    ebx,0x402050
22b:    8b 1b                   mov    ebx,DWORD PTR [ebx]
22d:    66 89 1d 3a 20 40 00    mov    WORD PTR ds:0x40203a,bx
234:    31 db                   xor    ebx,ebx
236:    8a 1d 12 20 40 00       mov    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x402012
23c:    01 db                   add    ebx,ebx
23e:    81 c3 50 20 40 00       add    ebx,0x402050
244:    8b 1b                   mov    ebx,DWORD PTR [ebx]
246:    66 89 1d 3c 20 40 00    mov    WORD PTR ds:0x40203c,bx
24d:    31 db                   xor    ebx,ebx
24f:    8a 1d 13 20 40 00       mov    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x402013
255:    01 db                   add    ebx,ebx
257:    81 c3 50 20 40 00       add    ebx,0x402050
25d:    8b 1b                   mov    ebx,DWORD PTR [ebx]
25f:    66 89 1d 3e 20 40 00    mov    WORD PTR ds:0x40203e,bx
266:    31 db                   xor    ebx,ebx
268:    8a 1d 16 20 40 00       mov    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x402016
26e:    01 db                   add    ebx,ebx
270:    81 c3 50 20 40 00       add    ebx,0x402050
276:    8b 1b                   mov    ebx,DWORD PTR [ebx]
278:    66 89 1d 41 20 40 00    mov    WORD PTR ds:0x402041,bx
27f:    31 db                   xor    ebx,ebx
281:    8a 1d 17 20 40 00       mov    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x402017
287:    01 db                   add    ebx,ebx
289:    81 c3 50 20 40 00       add    ebx,0x402050
28f:    8b 1b                   mov    ebx,DWORD PTR [ebx]
291:    66 89 1d 43 20 40 00    mov    WORD PTR ds:0x402043,bx
298:    31 db                   xor    ebx,ebx
29a:    8a 1d 18 20 40 00       mov    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x402018
2a0:    01 db                   add    ebx,ebx
2a2:    81 c3 50 20 40 00       add    ebx,0x402050
2a8:    8b 1b                   mov    ebx,DWORD PTR [ebx]
2aa:    66 89 1d 45 20 40 00    mov    WORD PTR ds:0x402045,bx
2b1:    31 db                   xor    ebx,ebx
2b3:    8a 1d 19 20 40 00       mov    bl,BYTE PTR ds:0x402019
2b9:    01 db                   add    ebx,ebx
2bb:    81 c3 50 20 40 00       add    ebx,0x402050
2c1:    8b 1b                   mov    ebx,DWORD PTR [ebx]
2c3:    66 89 1d 47 20 40 00    mov    WORD PTR ds:0x402047,bx
2ca:    6a 00                   push   0x0
2cc:    6a 00                   push   0x0
2ce:    6a 12                   push   0x12
2d0:    68 38 20 40 00          push   0x402038
2d5:    57                      push   edi
2d6:    ff 15 80 30 40 00       call   DWORD PTR ds:0x403080        //WriteFile
2dc:    6a 02                   push   0x2
2de:    6a 00                   push   0x0
2e0:    6a 00                   push   0x0
2e2:    57                      push   edi
2e3:    ff 15 90 30 40 00       call   DWORD PTR ds:0x403090        //SetPointer
2e9:    a1 10 20 40 00          mov    eax,ds:0x402010
2ee:    3b 05 1c 20 40 00       cmp    eax,DWORD PTR ds:0x40201c    //16,777,216 times.
2f4:    0f 85 25 fd ff ff       jne    0x1f                         //GOTO begin
2fa:    6a 00                   push   0x0
2fc:    68 00 20 40 00          push   0x402000
301:    68 00 20 40 00          push   0x402000
306:    6a 00                   push   0x0
308:    ff 15 98 30 40 00       call   DWORD PTR ds:0x403098        //MessageBoxA
30e:    6a 00                   push   0x0
310:    ff 15 78 30 40 00       call   DWORD PTR ds:0x403078        //ExitProcess
```

A program written in python does the job in 35 minutes, in assembler in 210 minutes. I understand that time is relative and everything depends on the hardware and the workload of the computer ... but still.

So here are the parameters of my system:

Windows 10.0.19044.2486

x64-based PC

2 processors

Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9 GenuineIntel ~1600

4.00 Gb RAM

NVIDIA GeForce GT 630

Can anyone explain to me why a program written in python (and very crookedly written, because I'm sure it can be optimized) does its job 6 times faster than a program written in assembler???

Comment: It is a *bad* program written in assembly?

Comment: For example because you invoke `WriteFile` 16 million times, while the python environment may use buffering? Also, did you make sure your counter at `0x402010` and your limit at `0x40201c` is properly initialized?

Comment: If you want asm to run fast, don't store/reload everything to memory.  Use registers; that's what they're for.  Also, process more than 1 byte at a time.  Using asm makes it easier than most languages to use SIMD, like `pxor` to XOR 16 bytes at once.  But probably most importantly, and what could explain being even slower than Python, is don't make frequent system calls.  Create a much larger buffer of output.  I'm guessing the `push 0x12` is a size for WriteFile?  That means you're writing in 18 byte chunks, super tiny, paying that large overhead very frequently.

Comment: no, it's not a bad program. It just performs calculations for example input d1d34fcc output 3a6c4e5d

Comment: Scott meant "bad" as in "inefficient, poorly optimized, not well written".  Not that it produces incorrect results.  There are lots of ways code can be bad but still produce correct results, including other reasons like being hard to maintain, but in this case inefficient is the #1 way in which this is "bad".

Comment: It's not the calculations that are slow. Comment out the file stuff and see how fast it actually is. I would expect it runs under 1 second (16M loops are not a whole lot with such simple arithmetic).

Comment: @Jester: There is of course a *lot* of room for improvement in the performance of this code even apart from the I/O.  e.g. stuff like `movzx ebx, byte ptr [mem]` instead of `xor ebx, ebx` / `mov bl, [mem]`.  Or `movzx ebx, word ptr [0x402050 + ebx*2]` instead of `add ebx,ebx` / `add ebx, 0x402050` / `mov  ebx,DWORD PTR [ebx]` (and then store BX, so we really only needed a word load, the dword load might cross a cache line boundary or create a store-forwarding stall.)  And I suspect some store/reload could be eliminated.  And those byte XORs could be a lot more efficient with SIMD or even SWAR.

Comment: Yes, of course. My point is, even this unoptimized version should do 16M loops under a second, not 3.5 hours. I have patched the binary, and it does seem to :)

Comment: As I understand it, the maximum possible buffer in the WriteFile function is 0xffff ffff and it is possible to create a separate section by allocating such an amount of memory to it. And call WriteFile once after this section is completely filled in?

Comment: Actually even the original unmodified code runs in 30 seconds ... so if it takes 210 minutes something is seriously wrong. Maybe a virus scanner or something constantly trying to analyze the stuff written to the file.

Comment: @Jester When I changed the jmp address to the beginning of the program in the hex-editor, windows guard wrote that it was a Trojan:Win32/Waratah.H!ml But I made it an exception

Comment: @Jester: Sure, I'd believe 30 seconds with no I/O.  Probably something closer to 1 second is possible with `pshufb` SIMD optimization of the shuffle and XOR stuff and the branching / conditionals, also avoiding the store/reload.  With Spectre mitigation enabled, system call overhead can be pretty high, but you're right, 210 *minutes* is extremely slow.  `210*60*60 * 3e9 / (16*2^20)` is about 135183334 cycles (135M) per system call, assuming a 3GHz Sandybridge.  Or 45 milliseconds per call.  That's only explicable with something like a virus scan.  (Or uncached synced I/O to a rotational disk!)

Comment: Thanks guys now the program works in 3 seconds now i have 1 WriteFile and buffer 0x1200 0000